# Get the last 24 hour job record form msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want write a query to get the last 24 hours worth of job record from the "msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory" table, but I can't get because I get the "run_date" and "run_time" columns are returned as a number. How can I convert the "run_date" and "run_time" columns into a datetime variable, and use this to get the last 24 hour job history?

Comment: can you post some examples of the numbers you have?  Or do you know the format?  They might be epoch seconds, milliseconds, or formatted 20101008123456, or something else - which it is will affect the answer.

Comment: i get the run_date in format like 20100628

and run_time like 192649

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-get-the-correct-date/time-from-the-msdb-sysjob-tables.html) - it shows how to "decode" those `run_date` columns from `sysjobhistory`.

You should be able to get the entries from the last 24 hours with a query something like this:

```
SELECT 
    j.name as JobName, 
    LastRunDateTime = 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + ' ' 
    + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'), 121)
FROM 
    msdb..sysjobs j
INNER JOIN
    msdb..sysjobhistory jh ON j.job_id = jh.job_id
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date, 112) + ' ' 
    + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_time), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'), 121) > DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for replys.actually i m executing the folloing query::
select sysjobs.job_id,sysjobs.name,sysjobhistory.step_name,sysjobhistory.message,sysjobhistory.run_status,sysjobhistory.run_date,sysjobhistory.run_time,sysjobhistory.run_duration,sysjobs.date_created,sysjobs.date_modified,sysjobs.version_number from sysjobhistory Inner join sysjobs on sysjobhistory.job_id=sysjobs.job_id

how i can get record according to datetime filter

Answer (score 3):

For databases after 2000, there is a function in the msdb database you can call that will return datetime:

```
msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) as 'RunDateTime'
```

If you are using sql 2000, you can copy the source of that function from a later version and create it in your instance of 2000.  I wish I could take credit for all of this, but I originally found it here: [mssqltips.com](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data)

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker of mine pointed out that the other given solutions only find jobs that we're **started** 24 hours ago (or less), not jobs that were **completed** 24 hours ago (or less). He proposed something along the lines of the following to location completed jobs:

```
SELECT j.name AS JobName
    ,LastCompletedDateTime = DATEADD(day, (run_duration / 240000), CONVERT(DATETIME, msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time))) + 
        STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(STR((run_duration % 240000), 7, 0), ' ', '0'), 4, 0, ':'), 7, 0, ':')
FROM msdb..sysjobs j
INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobhistory jh ON j.job_id = jh.job_id
WHERE DATEADD(day, (run_duration / 240000), CONVERT(DATETIME, msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time))) + 
    STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(STR((run_duration % 240000), 7, 0), ' ', '0'), 4, 0, ':'), 7, 0, ':') > DATEADD(HOUR, - 24, GETDATE())
```

I believe part of this comes from a blog, but we cannot locate it, when I do I'll link that as well...